# Can I change request header in Express node?

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing test for Express node.
I am trying to change content type header in request. But I did not find any ***set*** method in ***request***

Here is the link I am look up.
https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

My question is Can't the content type header be changed?

Comment: Why would you want to change it?

Comment: Even if you manage to change the header, there is no use case for it. In fact, it might cause serious issues for any middleware down the line that depends on the content types.

Comment: create some middleware and use [setHeader](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value)

Comment: @Robert This is for requests sent by Node, not received.

Comment: I tried **request.setHeader(name, value)**  but it shows **TypeError: req.headers is not a function**

Below is my code
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  req.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  res.format({
    text: function () {
      res.send(
        users
          .map(function (user) {
            return " - " + user.name + "\n";
          })
          .join("")
      );
    },
    html: function () {

Comment: Thanks for your replies:) What I am trying to test is res.format() which **Performs content-negotiation on the Accept HTTP header on the request object, when present. It uses req.accepts() to select a handler for the request, based on the acceptable types ordered by their quality values**  The log shows the following and the html handler is selected. But I am trying to let text or json be selected. req.accepts: [ 'text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml', 'image/webp', 'application/xml', '/' ]

Comment: I think I have resolved my original problem. I changed the handlers in code instead of the header in request and my original problem is resolved. Thank you All!